# Como remover um arquivo de um repositório Git sem deletá-lo localmente?

Tags: git

Eu gostaria de remover um arquivo ou diretório que foi enviado ao repositório Git erroneamente, mas sem removê-lo dos meus arquivos locais. Qual comando `git` executa tal ação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe o parâmetro `--cached` para o [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

`git rm --cached arquivo.txt`

Para diretórios, remova recursivamente com `-r`:

`git rm --cached -r diretorio`